# comment with line-filling equation gets garbled, with signature on top of text

Tags: bug, mathjax

The display of [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131021/constrained-optimization-problems-resulting-in-equal-variable-assignments/131082#comment302292_131082) is badly corrupted in my browser (Firefox 11.0 on Mac OS 10.6.8). The signature gets displayed on top of the end of the text. Since the comment contains an equation that fills a whole line, this may be related to [this other bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953/spurious-space-within-number) I filed earlier today.

Here's a screen shot:

[image: garbled comments]

Note that the second comment is also being rendered incorrectly, with the text interleaved with the equation.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q3t3g.png0) is what I see with the same browser/OS and it looks fine to me. Could you add a screen shot of what you see?

Comment: @t.b.: Sorry, I'd meant to add a screen shot and then got distracted. I've added one. In the meantime I noticed that the comment below it (also in the screen shot) is also being rendered incorrectly, with the text interleaved with the equation. That's also correct in your screen shot.

Comment: I don't see that, with Firefox 11.0 running on a PC with Windows 7.

Comment: I'm on FF 11.0 as well, although on Linux (Arch 64bit/kernel 3.3.1), and the comments in the page have a linebreak mid-$\LaTeX$. It works fine here, but I suspect this is what causing problems to begin with.